# Propiedades en instancia vs en clase, C orientando a objetos con glib (GTK+)

Tags: c, gtk

sin tantos rodeos ojala me puedan ayudar con algo que me tiene varado una semana entera, tengo una seria confusión con GTK+ y su sistema de objetos, leyendo la documentación del proyecto GNOME entendí que utiliza GType para tener una lista de todos los objetos y sus propiedades y `GObject` es una clase abstracta con toda las funciones requeridas básicamente.

Ahora mi confusión esta en la las dos funciones `_init` y `class_init`, una inicializa la instancia de la clase o el objeto y la otra la clase como tal, dentro de `class_init` hay que inicializar toda las propiedades, funciones virtuales etc, pero me encontré con el mecanismo para las propiedades de objetos, explicado [aquí](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html)  y quede muy perdido. ¿Por qué las propiedades no van en la estructura del objeto?, buscando un poco me encontré con [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840456/purpose-of-gvalue-gtypevaluetable-gtypeinfo-and-gparamspec) en esta comunidad  la cual me explicó a medias pero me dejó la otra mitad aún en duda, les muestro mis dos estructuras:

**Estructura del objeto**

```
struct _WindowPrincipal
{
  GtkWindow *padre;

  GtkMenuBar *menuBar;
  GtkDrawingArea *areaDibujo;
  GtkGrid *grid;        
};
```

**Estructura de la clase**

```
struct _WindowPrincipalClass
{
    GtkWindowClass *clasePadre;

    GtkMenuBar (*menu) ();
    void (*design) (WindowPrincipal *self);
};
```

Como pueden ver no tienen nada del otro mundo, en `_WindowPrincipal` defino el padre que es un `GtkWindow` y las propiedades de esa instancia, tiene un menú, una área de dibujo y una grilla para el diseño de la ventana, en la estructura de la clase dos funciones para el diseño del menú y el diseño de la ventana.

En la función `class_init` se registran las propiedades con `GParamType`, pero no le encuentro lógica a esto, osea entonces, ¿para qué defino las propiedades en la estructura del objeto si en `class_init` las voy a registrar a la clase y al objeto respectivamente? ¿qué lógica tiene eso? ¿o acaso me estoy confundiendo con dos cosas que no tienen nada que ver? la verdad no logro entenderlo.

Comment: ¿Y el C orientado a objetos donde está?

Comment: Son esas dos estructuras, una es la instancia del objeto y la otra de la clase, y con GType se registran al sistema de tipo, de esa manera se consigue herencia y polimorfismo, aunque no todas las tecnicas de POO ya que C no fue pensado para soportar este paradigma de programación

Comment: me estas mareando.. objeto.. clase.. instacia.. una instacia de una clase, ES una instancia de un objeto, porque un objeto es una clase. No hay clases que no sean objetos. como mucho habla clases abstractas que no generar un objeto de por si, pero al dejar de ser abstractas son un objeto. La confusion vendra por ahi?

Comment: @gbianchi Si asi es, un objeto como tal es una clase a la que ya se instancio y se le asigno memoria, pero con respecto a las dos estructuras es la manera en que se las ingenio GLIB para darle soporte a POO en C, échale un ojo al siguiente link https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gtype-instantiable-classed.html

Comment: Te recuerdo que C++ nació como un conjunto de macros sobre C... lo que se pueda hacer con C++ se puede hacer también con C solo que te lo tienes que currar a mano... no es automático... una de las pocas excepciones podrían ser las plantillas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C no admite, de forma nativa, herencia ni polimorfismo porque no está orientado a objetos... sin embargo sí que hay mecanismos que permiten simular este comportamiento... pero hay que programarlos a mano.

Así, hay que implementar de forma manual una serie de utilidades:

- Herencia de tipos: En C no existe el concepto de herencia... como mucho admite la composición.
- Polimorfismo: Dado que no existen objetos, C no te va a dar información sobre si un tipo puede convertirse de forma segura en otro (como sí hace `dynamic_cast` en C++)
- Funciones virtuales: Hay que encontrar un mencanismo que permita trabajar con funciones virtuales (una clase puede sobreescribir el comportamiento de la clase padre)
- Encapsulamiento: En C **todo** es público. No existen los modificadores de acceso por lo que nada impide que alguien modifique una variable miembro de tu objeto.

Obviamente no es necesario implementar todas estas características... pero dependiendo del diseño que te propongas sí que puede ser necesario implementar más de una.

**¿Cómo funciona GTK?**

C no da soporte nativo multitud de características de C++, por lo que si queremos emular alguna de esas características hay que programarla a mano.

En C++:

- La **clase** es un tipo de dato y determina la interfaz de los objeto.
- El **objeto** es la variable que se crea para una clase dada

Es decir:

```
class POO // <-- clase, es un tipo
{
public:
  int var; // <<-- interfaz de la clase
};

POO poo;      // <<-- poo es un objeto
poo.var = 10; // <<-- accedemos a las propiedades de poo,
              //      que vienen determinadas por su clase
```

Sin embargo en GTK han optado por aislar estos dos conceptos por, entre otros motivos, aislamiento, reutilización:

- aislamiento: Los punteros a función podrían ser modificados fácil e inadvertidamente, lo que corrompería la aplicación. Con esta solución los punteros a función se encuentran fuera de alcance y es GTK quien los gestiona.
- reutilización: Todos los objetos de una misma clase usan los mismos punteros a función, luego no es necesario replicar dichos punteros en cada objeto creado... con que exista una única copia es suficiente.

Así pues, en GTK, tienes una estructura para gestionar los punteros a función y otra para gestionar las variables miembro:

```
// Objeto: Solo tiene las variables miembro
struct _WindowPrincipal
{
  GtkWindow *padre;

  GtkMenuBar *menuBar;
  GtkDrawingArea *areaDibujo;
  GtkGrid *grid;        
};

// Clase: Gestiona los punteros a función
struct _WindowPrincipalClass
{
    GtkWindowClass *clasePadre;

    GtkMenuBar (*menu) ();
    void (*design) (WindowPrincipal *self);
};
```

Estas dos clases se acaban enlazando entre sí en el núcleo de GTK con la configuración posterior que hay que hacer. Fíjate que hasta el momento el único contacto que estas estructuras han tenido con GTK se limitan a incluir estructuras y punteros propios de GTK... en ningún momento le hemos dicho a GTK que debe tratar un nuevo tipo y menos aún cómo debe tratarlo.

Tu planteamiento inicial es bueno pero aun no has configurado el entorno de GTK para que sepa trabajar con tu tipo.

Comment: De hecho eso lo tengo ya, paso la información de las dos estructuras con sus respectivos constructores, propiedades etc, pero tenia esa seria duda porque a pesar de que servia no lo entendía, y no le encontraba lógica del porque era así. Ya me queda muchas cosas claras.